# Read PDF File into html not browser

Tags: php, html, pdf

I want to display .pdf file content in my php website. I already tried with a simple code like this:

```
#[Route('/pdf', name: 'app_pdf')]
    public function pdfAction()
    {
        $path = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir').'\public\build\images\tracemonkey.pdf';

        $response = new BinaryFileResponse($path);

        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        $response->setContentDisposition(
            ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE,
            'tracemonkey.pdf'
        );

        return $response;
    }
```

Its working fine but it showing me the pdf in browser so my question is: It is possible to know how to display a pdf not in the browser but in an html tag? (Here in my p.pdf)
How to read pdf file in my p.pdf ?

```css
.container-news {
     width: 100%;
     background-color: white;
}
 .container-news .news-header {
     width: 100%;
     margin: 15px auto;
     text-align: left;
     border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
 .container-news .news-header h1 {
     font-size: 1.5rem;
     margin: 0;
}
 .container-news .news-body {
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
}
 .container-news .news-body .news-card {
     width: 25%;
     background-color: #f7f7f7;
     margin: 5px 0;
     padding: 5px;
}
 .container-news .news-body .news-card .news-title h2 {
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 1.3rem;
     margin: 0;
     min-height: 40px;
     line-height: 3rem;
}
 .container-news .news-body .news-content h3 {
     font-size: 0.8rem;
     margin: 0;
}
 .container-news .news-body .news-content a {
     float: right;
}
 .pdf {
     min-height: 150px;
     border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-news">
        <div class="news-header">
            <h1>Dernière actualités</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="news-body">

            <div class="news-card rounded">
                <div class="news-title">
                    <h2>Cours SQL (lesson)</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="news-content">
                    <h3>Catégorie: <span class="alert-success">Informatique/Programmation</span></h3>
                    <p class="text-muted mt-4">SQL, pour Structured Query Language, est un langage qui permet d'interroger une base de données relationnelle afin de pouvoir modifier...</p>
                  <p class="pdf">SHOW PDF FILES HERE</p>
                    <a href="#">En voir plus</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="news-card">
                <div class="news-title">
                    <h2>Cours SQL (lesson)</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="news-content">
                    <h3>Catégorie: <span class="alert-success">Informatique/Programmation</span></h3>
                    <p class="text-muted mt-4">SQL, pour Structured Query Language, est un langage qui permet d'interroger une base de données relationnelle afin de pouvoir modifier...</p>
                  <p class="pdf">SHOW PDF FILES HERE</p>
                    <a href="#" class="">En voir plus</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="news-card">
                <div class="news-title">
                    <h2>Cours SQL (lesson)</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="news-content">
                    <h3>Catégorie: <span class="alert-success">Informatique/Programmation</span></h3>
                    <p class="text-muted mt-4">SQL, pour Structured Query Language, est un langage qui permet d'interroger une base de données relationnelle afin de pouvoir modifier...</p>
                  <p class="pdf">SHOW PDF FILES HERE</p>
                    <a href="#">En voir plus</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can not just mix binary PDF content in with HTML. If you want to display your PDF _inside_ of an HTML document - then you need to use an `iframe` or `object` element for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the solution !